# ASP.NET Active Sessions Grow Indefinitely

Tags: asp.net

Using PerfMon, I can see that my ASP.NET Applications (**Total**)\Sessions Active is growing indefinitely to the tens of thousands, and I suspect this is causing a recent performance degradation we are observing.

The growth appears to be around a few dozen per minute.

We are using .Net 4.5 and IIS 7.5

How can I get a sample of some details regarding these sessions using administrative tools? What could cause this? What next steps can I take to diagnose this odd behavior?

Comment: Growing over what time period? Tens of thousands per minute? Over a day? Over a year? What is the rate (quantity / time) that you are seeing? Also you need to provide some information on your environment. Do you mean asp.net sessions as in session store info? If so are you using in process or sql server or other? Anything else you can tell us like the version of .net, version of IIS, asp.net configuration settings that might relate?

Comment: @Igor added the information. I do believe those are asp.net sessions as that is the name of the performance counter.

Comment: @GuillaumeCR - There is no administrative tooling solution here. It is your code which manages the sessions. If you are asking for a tool to do this then that is off topic here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @TravisJ Thanks. If you want to undelete your suggested answer I will mark it as valid. I have to say I am a little surprised that this is such an uncommon problem that there would be no IIS tooling behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place a hook on the Session_OnStart event (more on those events at MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178583.aspx).

From there you should examine and escalate depending on the situation.

First, simply place a breakpoint inside of the event handler and do some normal browsing in your development environment. You can use incognito windows in chrome to achieve anonymity for the sake of creating sessions. If you need to do this in production then you should set up some sort of logging database or leverage your existing logging database to record the session requests (you can serialize them temporarily if you need all of the data).

Look at what the request path is for these sessions, and at some of the contextual data in general. If there are erroneous sessions the handler should be called multiple times per request and that should be immediately obvious. From there you can determine how to handle the extra paths or requests that are coming in.

Since you tagged this asp.net, it is hard to tell what exact version or framework associated with that you are using. However, in general I have noticed that many browsers will accidentally cause an extra session for requesting resources, *especially the favicon*.

It is highly recommended that you do not create sessions for favicons. In asp.net mvc you can do that by ignoring the route. In asp.net mvc you can also ignore excessive resources. That is done in the global.asax.cs file like this

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");
```

See if you have a place in your application that you can do this if the extra sessions are being created as a result of these types of requests.

Comment: We cannot repro on our dev environments, and I'd like an administrative tooling solution before I try any code changes.